# Apache 2.4 Unrecognized header format %

Tags: configuration, apache-2.4

Using Apache 2.4 and followed the examples here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html

Here is my code

```
<If "!%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#files/cache/static/[A-Za-z_\-0-9]+.cache#"> 
    Header set foo-checksum "expr=%{md5:foo}"
</If>
```

I'm just playing at the moment but as soon as I use

```
    Header set foo-checksum "expr=%{md5:foo}"
```

As per their example - I get

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 130 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
httpd[19459]: Unrecognized header format %
httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

On apache start. Any ideas?
I've tried it outside of an expression as well and it gives the same error

Other expressions work.

Answer (score 7):

You need to be using Apache v2.4.10 or above and as Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ships with v2.4.7 this is most likely what you are using. The [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html) mentions this briefly at the start of the Header directive docs:

> Compatibility:    SetIfEmpty available in 2.4.7 and later, **expr=value
>   available in 2.4.10 and later**

I ran up a couple of servers to confirm this works

Apache v2.4.12:

```
root@ubuntu-server:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily

root@ubuntu-server:~# cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf 
<VirtualHost *:80>
Header set foo-checksum "expr=%{md5:foo}"
</VirtualHost>

root@ubuntu-server:~# apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 24 2015 15:59:00

root@ubuntu-server:~# service apache2 reload

root@ubuntu-server:~# curl -I localhost
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 07 Mar 2016 21:15:38 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Mon, 07 Mar 2016 20:57:04 GMT
ETag: "2c39-52d7bb502f118"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 11321
Vary: Accept-Encoding
foo-checksum: acbd18db4cc2f85cedef654fccc4a4d8
Content-Type: text/html
```

but not on Apache v2.4.7:

```
root@ubuntu-server:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

root@ubuntu-server:~# cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf 
<VirtualHost *:80>
Header set foo-checksum "expr=%{md5:foo}"
</VirtualHost>

root@ubuntu-server:~# apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jan 14 2016 17:45:23

root@ubuntu-server:~# service apache2 reload
 * Reloading web server apache2                                                                                                                   * 
 * The apache2 configtest failed. Not doing anything.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
Unrecognized header format %
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Comment: We're on httpd `2.4.48` (CentOS 7) and still getting this error.